# How to access the object a selected row is representing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `SortablebindingList<Record>` as a `DataSource` for my `DataGridView`. I also have `dataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick` mapped to my `selectionDblClicked()` fuction.

```
dataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(selectionDblClicked);
```

...

```
        void selectionDblClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with the underlying `record` object...

    }
```

Now, EventHandlers pass a `sender` object and an `EventArgs` argument.

My question is how does one use the `DataGridViewCellEventHandler` to access the underlying object that was "double clicked"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DataBoundItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the clicked row.

To see which row was clicked, use RowIndex property of [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
void selectionDblClicked(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var rowClicked = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DoSomething(rowClicked.DataBoundItem as Record);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, I'll give this a try. I'll mark it correct as soon as I test it out.